# How to disable configserver Health page checking for default label git

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, configserver

I have simple config server implementation and when i browse `/health` end point I get:

```
{ 
  status:"UP",
  "details":{
    "configserver":{
       "status":"UP",
       "details":{
        "repositories":[
           {
              ...
```

How can I stop this where my config server is check the configserver health again. This is causing the config server to make multiple calls to git which is not needed in my scenario.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I found that the below comment does not actually work as it still outputs the propertySources object.

Answer (score 5):

set `spring.cloud.config.server.health.enabled=false`